# Segmentation fault loading texture with Devil into OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, texture2d, freeglut, devil

I am attempting to load a texture into OpenGL using Devil, and i am having a segmentation fault upon the calling of this constructor

```
Sprite::Sprite(const char *path){

    ILuint tex = 0;

    ilutEnable(ILUT_OPENGL_CONV);
    ilGenImages(1, &tex);
    ilBindImage(tex);
    ilLoadImage(path);
    ilConvertImage(IL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
    width  = (GLuint*)ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
    height = (GLuint*)ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0,
                 GL_RGBA,
                 width,
                 height,
                 0,
                 GL_RGBA,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 &tex);

    ilBindImage(0);
    ilDeleteImages(1, &tex);
    ilutDisable(ILUT_OPENGL_CONV);

}
```

and texture is a protected member

```
GLuint texture;
```

As soon as this constructor is called i recieve a segfault error and it exits and I am using freeglut, gl, il, ilu, and ilut. any help would be appreciated

Edit:

I also decided to take a different approach and use

`texture = ilutGLLoadImage(path)`

function to just load it directly into the gl texture because I located the segfault coming from

```
ilLoadImage(path)
```

but the compiler tells me that ilutGLLoadImage() is not declared in this scope, and i have IL/il.h IL/ilu.h and IL/ilut.h all included and initialized

Comment: Also i am very fairly new to opengl and this is the very first time i have tried anything with image loading or textures so i may be using some of the functions very wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used DevIL, but `glTexImage2D` wants pointer to pixel data as the last argument and you pass pointer to local variable `tex` there instead, which is allocated on stack and does not contain expected information. So `glTexImage2D` reads through your stack and eventually attempts to access memory it was not supposed to access and you get segmentation fault.

I guess you'd want to use `ilGetData()` instead.

Comment: i tried that and i still get a seg fault, what your saying makes sense but wouldnt ilGetData() reference the same memory as &tex?

Comment: `tex` is of type `ILuint` and is allocated on stack, therefore it occupies fixed amount of memory (and is likely just typedef for `usigned int`), you cannot possibly load arbitrarily sized image into it. So it's very likely just a descriptor similar to the one you get by calling `glGenTextures`. Run your program with debugger attached, you would be able to figure out exact crash location.

Comment: I was able to find it as you can see in the edit above, but that was just by going through and commenting out one line at a time and running the program to find when it wouldnt crash, how can i have gdb enter that function instead of just main? when i use it it only debugs main

Comment: Your code lacks error checking. Are you sure image loads fine?

Comment: Would an invalid load cause a segmentation fault? i had thought that the memory would still be allocated like a null pointer

Comment: When trying to print the iLoadImage function because it returns a boolean the segfault occurs and the program terminates before the function can return

Comment: I"m not sure what you are talking about, but if `ilGetData()` returns null pointer, it will very well cause segmentation fault when you'd try to read from it.

Comment: the problem is that my program never gets that far as it exits at ilLoadImage

Comment: Now since you know where it crashes you can start removing stuff until it stops. Or create [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with `ilLoadImage()` call to see if it reproduces with minimal code.

Comment: So i setup a MCVE and after playing around a little i found out that it has something to do with the image that i load, because after changing the image the segmentation fault went away, but then would happen again with other images so i think it has something to do with opengl. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have DevIL initialized with `ilInit (  )` and change `&tex` to `ilGetData (  )` and then it should work.